# Парсинг вещественного числа из строки

Tags: c++, строки

Задание звучит следующим образом:

> Дана строка символов, состоящая из букв, цифр, запятых, точек, знаков
> «+» и «–». Выделить подстроку, которая соответствует записи вещественного
> числа с плавающей точкой.

Вот код, который я написал:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>;

int main()
{
    char* str = new char();
    std::cin >> str;

    double found = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        char* cp = new char();
        std::copy(str + i, str + strlen(str), cp);
        found = atof(cp);

        if (found != 0) {
            std::cout << found;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Идея алгоритма заключается в следующем: пользователь вводит какую-то строку, которая потенциально содержит в себе подстроку в виде вещественного числа, например `test string -298.2 continue test string`. Поскольку функция `atof` корректно парсит такое число из строки в случае, если строка *начинается* с него, я решил проходиться циклом по строке и последовательно применять данную функцию, каждый раз начиная со следующего символа, пока не будет успешно считано число. Но такой подход, почему-то, не работает. Точнее работает, но только если число находится в самом начале, а если окружено другими символами, то нет. То есть работает так же, как и `atof` без цикла.

Как можно улучшить алгоритм (при том, что использовать `atof` обязательно и строка - это именно массив символов) или как исправить имеющийся код? В C++ я почти ничего не смыслю.

Comment: Функция `atof` даст 0 при применении к неверной строке (типа "test"), а в случае -298.2 вы просто применяете ее к целой пачке разных корректных значений — `-298.2`, `298.2`, `98.2`, ...

Comment: @Harry поправил код. Добавил выход из цикла в случае, если что-то было считано.

Comment: @Harry то есть сейчас проблема заключается в том, что у меня не получается игнорировать нечисловые символы в начале строки.

Comment: Проблема еще и в том, что условие нечеткое. Каждый ответ — и 298.2, и 98.2 и прочие — все правильные. А нужен один. Какой? может, максимально длинный? :)

Comment: @Harry согласен. Пускай это будет первое найденное.

Comment: Тогда надо найти первую цифру, и если перед ней знак `+` или `-` — соответственно сместиться влево.

Comment: @Harry предположим, я нашел первую цифру, определил, что перед ней `-`. Как мне засунуть в `atof` подстроку, начиная с позиции этого символа и до конца строки?

Comment: Засовывайте просто указатель на этот первый символ, `atof` с лишним сам разберется...

Comment: @Harry https://pastebin.com/Nu70XSC8 - для случая, когда проверяется только двойка (а не любая из цифр), вывод всегда просто `2`. Почему?

Comment: @smellyshovel, почему обязательно `atof()`? imho [sscanf](http://www.nsc.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?scanf+3) (обратите внимание на формат `%n`) подходит для этой задачи значительно лучше

Comment: @avp задание такое. Я с Вами не спорю, но, видимо, кому-то очень хочется поизвращаться.

Comment: @smellyshovel, тогда вам надо будет самому распознавать все допустимые изображения нуля, если `atof()` вернет 0 (например `+.0e-0`)

Comment: @avp не думаю, что подобные edge-кейсы кого-то интересуют. Задача определенно не в этом. Если удастся распознать число, которое я привел в вопросе, этого будет достаточно.

Comment: Тогда ищите символ, который входит в `"+-.0123456789"`, передавайте его адрес в `atof()` и сравнивайте результат с 0. Если не равен, значит нашли. Копировать ничего никуда не надо. Что-то в духе `for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++) if (strchr("+-.1234567890", str[i])) if ((found = atof(str + i)) != 0) break;`

Comment: @avp почти как часы работает. Крашится, если после числа в строке ничего нет. А для `test-298.2test` все идеально. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @avp нет, даже не крашится, это мой косяк был. Все работает как надо. Благодарю.

Comment: @smellyshovel, успехов!

Comment: Блин, мы тут все о теории... а у вас практика-то жуткая! Вы же выделяете один(!) символ, куда читаете одно(!) слово и что-то там пытаетесь искать? У вас же классический UB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все как-то упустили, что в вашем коде явное UB, ибо вы выделяете мало памяти, да и читаете только одно слово, а не строку...

Вот немного переделанный ваш код, который вы на pastebin выложили, пробуйте. Добавил проверку на первую точку — ну, `-.2` ведь тоже нормальное число...

```
int main()
{
    char* str = new char[1000];
    cin.getline(str,1000);
 
    double found = 0;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            if (i && str[i-1] == '.') --i;
            if (i && ((str[i-1] == '-')||(str[i-1] == '+'))) --i;
            found = atof(str+i);
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << found;
    delete[] str;
}
```

Comment: Что значит UB? И почему передается в `atof` `str+i`? Как можно к массиву `char`'ов прибавить `int`?

Comment: UB — undefined behaviour, неопределенное поведение. `str+i` — арифметика указателей, точно то же самое, что и `&str[i]` (и `&i[str]`, кстати :))

Answer (score 1):

Подстрок может быть и много - ИМХО проще обернутьт в регуляру

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line{"blablabla -4.124 fsadfs 2.124"};
    std::regex rxp{"[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+"};
    std::smatch rgx_sm;
    std::size_t tot_pos{0};
    while (std::regex_search(line, rgx_sm, rxp))
    {
        std::cout << "Found at :" << rgx_sm.position() + tot_pos << " data : " << rgx_sm.str() << '\n';
        tot_pos = rgx_sm.prefix().length() + rgx_sm.str().length();
        line = rgx_sm.suffix();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, но в задании сказано выделить подстрокУ, а не подстрокИ. Так что, я думаю, можно считать, что нас интересует одна. Регулярки, к сожалению, использовать нельзя, хотя очевидно, что решение это наиболее логичное.